# How do I debug a *-pc-windows-msvc Rust program on windows using LLDB?

Tags: rust, lldb

I'm having problems debugging Rust programs with LLDB on windows.
LLDB doesn't seem to be able to find the PDB file, even though it's in the same directory as my binary.
I run LLDB from the command line on my binary and no luck.
I also tried using the --symfile option of the debuggers file command and it still won't display any debugging info.
Any ideas?